# Expected number of steps to get a run of six different faces in a dice - Markov chain

Tags: probability, matrices, markov-chains, expected-value

I try to solve this question by Markov Chain:

> A single die is rolled until a run of six different faces appears. For example, one might roll the sequence
> 535463261536435344151612534 with only the last six rolls all distinct. What is the expected number
> of rolls?

And I built the transition matrix

$P = \begin{bmatrix}  0&1&0&0&0&0&0\\ 0&1/6&5/6&0&0&0&0  \\0&1/6&1/6&4/6&0&0&0\\0&1/6&1/6&1/6&3/6&0&0\\0&1/6&1/6&1/6&1/6&2/6&0\\0&1/6&1/6&1/6&1/6&1/6&1/6\\0&0&0&0&0&0&1 \end{bmatrix}$

Where each row $i: 0,1,2...$ represents the state I have $i$ different results in a row (or the last $i$ rolls are all distinct) , and the column represent the probability of moving from state to state

Now I can get the matrix I want for computing expected steps :

$\mathbf N = (\mathbf I - \mathbf Q)^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}  1.00&1.50&2.50&5.00&15.00&-24.00 \\
-1.20&-0.30&-0.50&-1.00&-3.00&6.00 \\
0.00&-1.50&-0.50&-1.00&-3.00&6.00 \\
0.00&0.00&-2.00&-1.00&-3.00&6.00 \\
0.00&0.00&0.00&-3.00&-3.00&6.00 \\
0.00&0.00&0.00&0.00&-6.00&6.00  \end{bmatrix}$

And I do not understand why I do not get the desired result, since the first line amounts to 1 which is certainly not the expectation to get six distinguished faces.

Comment: What is the meaning of the rows/columns of the matrix ?

Comment: For example, when I get {1,2,3} and I am in state 3, then if I get 3 now (with a probability of 1/6) I go back to state 1 (because I need 6 different in a row and here there are 2 times 3) and if I get 2 I return to state 2 (because I have the beginning of a sequence - 3,2) and if it comes out 1 I stay in state 3 and only when it comes out 4 or 5 or 6 (3/6 probability) will I switch to state 4.

Comment: Can't you just give a definition of the states ?

Comment: state $i$ represent the last $i$ rolls are all distinct

Comment: What about $i=0$ and $i=1$ ?

Comment: the same.
state 0 represent the start of a game when I have no results yet
and state 1 - when I have only one result or when the one before the last is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get negative numbers for $N$. Your approach is fine, though. You must have made some numerical mistake?

In Matlab/Octave:

```
P = [ 0 6 0 0 0 0 0 ;
      0 1 5 0 0 0 0 ;
      0 1 1 4 0 0 0 ;
      0 1 1 1 3 0 0 ;
      0 1 1 1 1 2 0 ;
      0 1 1 1 1 1 1 ;
      0 0 0 0 0 0 6 ] / 6;

Q = P(1:6,1:6);

N = inv(eye(6)-Q)

 1.00   14.70   23.50   23.00   15.00    6.00
 0.00   14.70   23.50   23.00   15.00    6.00
 0.00   13.50   23.50   23.00   15.00    6.00
 0.00   13.20   22.00   23.00   15.00    6.00
 0.00   12.60   21.00   21.00   15.00    6.00
 0.00   10.80   18.00   18.00   12.00    6.00

N * ones(6,1)
 ans =

   83.2
   82.2
   81
   79.2
   75.6
   64.8
```

BTW, the "zero state" is rather trivial, it could be omitted, assuming we start after one iteration, and in the end add one to the expected result.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I did the calculations in Python, now I did again and got the correct return, I do not know what was my mistake before, I tried several times, anyway thanks again